# print pandas dataframe in pygame line by line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, networkx

I am trying to print my dataframe in pygame's window. I know it is not a really good thing to do, but I have to in order to let my data be seen and avoid normal print.

I have this dictionary:

```
Y = {a: dict(b) for a, b in X.items()}
print(Y)
```

the result is:

```
{(0, 0): {(0, 0): 0, (0, 1): 1, (0, 2): 2, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 4, (0, 5): 7, (1, 5): 6, (1, 0): 9, (2, 0): 8, (1, 1): 10, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 6, (1, 4): 5, (2, 1): 7, (2, 3): 7, (2, 4): 8, (2, 5): 9}, (0, 1): {(0, 1): 0, (0, 0): 1, (0, 2): 1, (0, 3): 2, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 3, (0, 5): 6, (1, 5): 5, (1, 0): 8, (2, 0): 7, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 5, (1, 4): 4, (2, 1): 6, (2, 3): 6, (2, 4): 7, (2, 5): 8}, (0, 2): {(0, 2): 0, (0, 1): 1, (0, 3): 1, (0, 0): 2, (1, 3): 2, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 5, (1, 5): 4, (1, 0): 7, (2, 0): 6, (1, 1): 8, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 4, (1, 4): 3, (2, 1): 5, (2, 3): 5, (2, 4): 6, (2, 5): 7}, (0, 3): {(0, 3): 0, (0, 2): 1, (1, 3): 1, (0, 4): 1, (0, 0): 3, (0, 1): 2, (0, 5): 4, (1, 5): 3, (1, 0): 6, (2, 0): 5, (1, 1): 7, (1, 2): 2, (2, 2): 3, (1, 4): 2, (2, 1): 4, (2, 3): 4, (2, 4): 5, (2, 5): 6}, (1, 3): {(1, 3): 0, (0, 3): 1, (1, 2): 1, (1, 4): 1, (0, 0): 4, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 2, (0, 4): 2, (0, 5): 3, (1, 5): 2, (1, 0): 5, (2, 0): 4, (1, 1): 6, (2, 2): 2, (2, 1): 3, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 4, (2, 5): 5}, (0, 4): {(0, 4): 0, (0, 3): 1, (0, 0): 4, (0, 1): 3, (0, 2): 2, (1, 3): 2, (0, 5): 5, (1, 5): 4, (1, 0): 7, (2, 0): 6, (1, 1): 8, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 4, (1, 4): 3, (2, 1): 5, (2, 3): 5, (2, 4): 6, (2, 5): 7}, (0, 5): {(0, 5): 0, (1, 5): 1, (0, 0): 7, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 5, (1, 0): 8, (2, 0): 7, (1, 1): 9, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 5, (1, 4): 2, (2, 1): 6, (2, 3): 6, (2, 4): 7, (2, 5): 8}, (1, 5): {(1, 5): 0, (0, 5): 1, (1, 4): 1, (0, 0): 6, (0, 1): 5, (0, 2): 4, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 2, (0, 4): 4, (1, 0): 7, (2, 0): 6, (1, 1): 8, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 4, (2, 1): 5, (2, 3): 5, (2, 4): 6, (2, 5): 7}, (1, 0): {(1, 0): 0, (2, 0): 1, (1, 1): 1, (0, 0): 9, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 7, (0, 5): 8, (1, 5): 7, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (1, 4): 6, (2, 1): 2, (2, 3): 4, (2, 4): 5, (2, 5): 6}, (2, 0): {(2, 0): 0, (1, 0): 1, (2, 1): 1, (0, 0): 8, (0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 6, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 6, (0, 5): 7, (1, 5): 6, (1, 1): 2, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 2, (1, 4): 5, (2, 3): 3, (2, 4): 4, (2, 5): 5}, (1, 1): {(1, 1): 0, (1, 0): 1, (0, 0): 10, (0, 1): 9, (0, 2): 8, (0, 3): 7, (1, 3): 6, (0, 4): 8, (0, 5): 9, (1, 5): 8, (2, 0): 2, (1, 2): 5, (2, 2): 4, (1, 4): 7, (2, 1): 3, (2, 3): 5, (2, 4): 6, (2, 5): 7}, (1, 2): {(1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 1, (2, 2): 1, (0, 0): 5, (0, 1): 4, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 3, (0, 5): 4, (1, 5): 3, (1, 0): 4, (2, 0): 3, (1, 1): 5, (1, 4): 2, (2, 1): 2, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 4}, (2, 2): {(2, 2): 0, (1, 2): 1, (2, 1): 1, (2, 3): 1, (0, 0): 6, (0, 1): 5, (0, 2): 4, (0, 3): 3, (1, 3): 2, (0, 4): 4, (0, 5): 5, (1, 5): 4, (1, 0): 3, (2, 0): 2, (1, 1): 4, (1, 4): 3, (2, 4): 2, (2, 5): 3}, (1, 4): {(1, 4): 0, (1, 3): 1, (1, 5): 1, (0, 0): 5, (0, 1): 4, (0, 2): 3, (0, 3): 2, (0, 4): 3, (0, 5): 2, (1, 0): 6, (2, 0): 5, (1, 1): 7, (1, 2): 2, (2, 2): 3, (2, 1): 4, (2, 3): 4, (2, 4): 5, (2, 5): 6}, (2, 1): {(2, 1): 0, (2, 0): 1, (2, 2): 1, (0, 0): 7, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 5, (0, 5): 6, (1, 5): 5, (1, 0): 2, (1, 1): 3, (1, 2): 2, (1, 4): 4, (2, 3): 2, (2, 4): 3, (2, 5): 4}, (2, 3): {(2, 3): 0, (2, 2): 1, (2, 4): 1, (0, 0): 7, (0, 1): 6, (0, 2): 5, (0, 3): 4, (1, 3): 3, (0, 4): 5, (0, 5): 6, (1, 5): 5, (1, 0): 4, (2, 0): 3, (1, 1): 5, (1, 2): 2, (1, 4): 4, (2, 1): 2, (2, 5): 2}, (2, 4): {(2, 4): 0, (2, 3): 1, (2, 5): 1, (0, 0): 8, (0, 1): 7, (0, 2): 6, (0, 3): 5, (1, 3): 4, (0, 4): 6, (0, 5): 7, (1, 5): 6, (1, 0): 5, (2, 0): 4, (1, 1): 6, (1, 2): 3, (2, 2): 2, (1, 4): 5, (2, 1): 3}, (2, 5): {(2, 5): 0, (2, 4): 1, (0, 0): 9, (0, 1): 8, (0, 2): 7, (0, 3): 6, (1, 3): 5, (0, 4): 7, (0, 5): 8, (1, 5): 7, (1, 0): 6, (2, 0): 5, (1, 1): 7, (1, 2): 4, (2, 2): 3, (1, 4): 6, (2, 1): 4, (2, 3): 2}}[!
```

Then, I can save it into a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Y)
df.index = [*df.index]
df.columns = [*df.columns] 
print(df)
```

and the result is:

```
        (0, 0)  (0, 1)  (0, 2)  (0, 3)  ...  (2, 1)  (2, 3)  (2, 4)  (2, 5)
(0, 0)       0       1       2       3  ...       7       7       8       9
(0, 1)       1       0       1       2  ...       6       6       7       8
(0, 2)       2       1       0       1  ...       5       5       6       7
(0, 3)       3       2       1       0  ...       4       4       5       6
(1, 3)       4       3       2       1  ...       3       3       4       5
(0, 4)       4       3       2       1  ...       5       5       6       7
(0, 5)       7       6       5       4  ...       6       6       7       8
(1, 5)       6       5       4       3  ...       5       5       6       7
(1, 0)       9       8       7       6  ...       2       4       5       6
(2, 0)       8       7       6       5  ...       1       3       4       5
(1, 1)      10       9       8       7  ...       3       5       6       7
(1, 2)       5       4       3       2  ...       2       2       3       4
(2, 2)       6       5       4       3  ...       1       1       2       3
(1, 4)       5       4       3       2  ...       4       4       5       6
(2, 1)       7       6       5       4  ...       0       2       3       4
(2, 3)       7       6       5       4  ...       2       0       1       2
(2, 4)       8       7       6       5  ...       3       1       0       1
(2, 5)       9       8       7       6  ...       4       2       1       0
```

My question is: Is it possible to print this last result on pygame? My idea is to save every line into an array and then print every line of the array alone and in the right order. I did it in this way:

```
def printAM(x, y, cella, df):
    arraydf = df.to_numpy()
    y_offset = 0
    for line in arraydf:
        textsurface = myfontsmall.render(str(line), False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(textsurface, (x, y+y_offset))
        y_offset += cella
    pygame.display.update()
```

But the result is not really good, as you can see from this [image of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpt6M.png).

How can I make it mode goodlooking? And do you think it is possible to have also the nodes' names as first line and as last column?

Thanks

Comment: For starters turn on text antialiasing for Font.render() (that "False").

Comment: I'm sorry, nothing changed...

Comment: I found out the problem is in ```arraydf = df.to_numpy()```... Do you know how to fix it?